Creating linear fits from an array that is too big in memory
I aim to work with a matrix of matrices with: shape(databse)=(100, 256, 5000, 5000)
To give some overarching perspective, 5000x5000 are the pixels of images taken, which store a single intensity value. The picture was taken with 256 different "illumination" settings and for each illumination settings it was taken 100 times.
This leaves me with a matrix of matrices where the data is ordered in the following way:
database=
[ [Illumination_1_Run_1 Illumination_2_Run_1 ......]
  [Illumination_2_Run_1 Illumination_2_Run_2 ......]
.
.
.                                              ]

Now the Illumination_i_Run_j elements are matrices themselves:
Illumination_i_Run_j=
[[Intensity_pixel_1_1 Intensity_pixel_2_1 ......]
 [Intensity_pixel_2_1 Intensity_pixel_2_2 ......]
.
.
.
.                                               ]

Before working with the real data I tried to create some dummy data using dummy_data=np.random.rand(100,256,5000,5000 )
However, this already gives me the message:
"MemoryError: Unable to allocate 4.66 TiB for an array with shape (100, 256, 5000, 5000) and data type float64"

Since the amount of data im working with is a lot.
What I aim to do with the images is to average the intensity of the pixels among the 100 runs for each illumination setting. This gives me: shape( averaged_database) = (256,5000,5000) which is still too big.
The next step would be to create a linear fit between the intensity of each pixel and its illumination. This would result in 5000x5000=25x10^6 fits.
Are there some libraries or techniques to use in order to avoid this memory problem?
General direction on how I could continue?

Settle for processing each lighting level individually as (100,5000,5000). You don't say how big your pixels are. 8bit, 16bit or 32bit? Then combine them into a (256, 5000,5000) result. What are you trying to do?
